# Link to external php file (for proprietary reasons)

Tags: php

So we've got a pretty nifty little PHP app. People have been interested in "leasing" it under a different name.

However, with the current setup - any "top tier admin" (which they would have to be) can view the PHP files.

My boss is a tad concerned with that. Would it be possible (or rather, SMART) to link to external PHP files on our server instead?

So instead of

**index.php contents:**

```
<?php include('/lib/header.php'); ?>
```

and consequently

**header.php contents:**

```
<?php /*Stuff I don't want you seeing*/ ?>
```

would it be possible (and if so, smart) to do something like this

**index.php contents:**

```
<?php include('http://site-i-control.com/lib/header.php'); ?>
```

so they couldn't see or modify the contents of header.php?

Comment: if you don't want to give it away host it on your end.

Comment: Unless you compiled it into an extension, there's no way to "hide" PHP code.  I guess you could obfuscate it...

Comment: proper licensing is the correct method of 'protection'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way you're going to be able to accomplish something like this in PHP is to:

1. Develop or otherwise implement code that uses a license key.
2. Encode all or part of the source code using IONcube, SourceGuardian, or other similar products.

Otherwise there is no way to protect PHP code in the way you require.

Answer (score 2):

Anyone would be able to put that URL in their browser and download it. In fact, just editing the code to `echo` instead of `include`, you get the see the code immediately.

If you release the PHP code, you're effectively giving them everything...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can compile your php:

[Php Compiler](http://www.phpcompiler.org/)

> What is phc?
>
> phc is an open source compiler for PHP with support for plugins. In
>   addition, it can be used to pretty-print or obfuscate PHP code, as a
>   framework for developing applications that process PHP scripts, or to
>   convert PHP into XML and back, enabling processing of PHP scripts
>   using XML tools.